# What is the difference between running a local host with npm or pnpm?

Tags: reactjs, vite, package.json

I'm in the console log and I want to execute my program with pnpm run dev, and it doesn't work, and looks like:

```
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pnpm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I just want to generate my localhost like always but instead of npm with pnpm

Comment: Did you run `pnpm install`? Are you in the correct directory?

Comment: The error means it cannot find the `pnpm` command/executable, as it says in the lines of the error that you did not quote, which means it is not on the PATH or not installed at all. The lines you did not quote are: _"pnpm : The term 'pnpm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."_

Comment: Did you run `npm i -g pnpm`, and do you have access to the global binaries?

Comment: Does the `pnpm --version` command work?

Comment: I was able to solve it. I had to modify some permissions from the bash.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call `run` with `pnpm`, just call `pnpm dev`.